# Count visible blank cells using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

When I enter the following function as a UDF in a cell:

```
Function VisibleBlankCells(r As Range) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    VisibleBlankCells = Intersect(r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)).Count
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

`r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` evaluates ALL cells in `r` as empty regardless of whether they contain text or not. What might be the cause of this and an alternative solution?

Comment: Have you tried removing your `On Error Resume Next` (shudder) statement to see if there's actually an error?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` for a start - you should always assume that your code will fail and account for it accordingly, simply ignoring errors will just complicate matters.

Secondly ,there is no need to use `Intersect` - just identify the visible cells directly, and then use a further `SpecialCells()` method to identify the blank child cells.

```
Function VisibleBlankCells(r As Range) As Long
    VisibleBlankCells = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
End Function
```

---

tested with this:

```
Sub test_code()
    Dim r As Range: Set r = Selection
    Debug.Print CountBlanks(r)
End Sub

Function CountBlanks(r As Range) As Long
    CountBlanks = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
End Function
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: 2010 ... more words bla

Comment: OP is using Excel 2013. xlCellTypeBlanks returns the "correct" address and count when I perform it on Selection. But incorrect when I use it as an UDF and perform it on r as range

Comment: I can only assume something with your data, I've tested this with `selection` and a UDF and it works fine for me in Excel 2010...

Comment: See my edit above and try using that code. This works fine for me I did the same thing.

Comment: Are you using the code in an actual code module - not a worksheet module or a workbook module?

Comment: Sorry - I'm overlooking the fact it's being used in a cell. This will work in a sub routine, but not in a cell because of the limitations of worksheet functions in Excel.

Comment: @Rory thought that too after reading on it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787/en-us). but I was wondering how it could work for S O. Deleting my earlier comments

Comment: @EngJon - it didn't work for me, I was overlooking the fact it was being used in a cell - which wouldn't work due to UDF limitations (from the MS article) "_For correct calculation, all ranges that are used in the calculation should be passed to the function as arguments._" - The range being used cannot be changed (i.e. using SpecialCells) inside the UDF, it has to be passed to it in the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of filter mechanism won't work in an UDF (see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787/en-us) for information on that). I suggest a looping inside your UDF:

```
Public Function VisibleBlankCells(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    i = 0
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Rows.Hidden = False And _
        cell.Columns.Hidden = False And _
        cell.Value = "" Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    VisibleBlankCells = i
End Function
```

However, there may be some problems regarding the updating and functionality:

1. The value of the UDF only updates after editing the referenced range or calling other UDFs. So if you hide a column or row in that range, it won't have an instant effect
2. In the (working) execution of your code in a Sub, the visible cells (also) refer to yet unused cells in your worksheet to be "not visible". In my solution however, all cells that are not contained in a hidden row/column are considered visible.